# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n*(n!)^2*4^n}{(2n)!} $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n*(n!)^2*4^n}{(2n)!} $ converge?

I have no idea how to do this. I have tried to use any trick I am aware of but can't figure this out.

Can anyone help please?

EDIT:

I have already found out that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n!)^2*4^n}{(2n)!} $ diverges using Raabe's test.

The ratio test is inconclusive for this series.

EDIT 2:

Using Stirling's approximation for $n!$ is not allowed.

Comment: Which tests have you applied? What was the result?

Comment: Context. What sort of class is this for?

Comment: How far did you get without any tricks? What are the numbers involved in (n!)^2 * 4^n / (2n)! ?

Comment: Looking at the comments I feel like I am missing something, but any convergence test I have tried to use has failed.

Comment: You add terms with alternating signs. What would be a necessary condition for convergence if the sign is alternating?

Comment: Hint: a necessary condition for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ to converge is $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$. Now [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) tells you.....

Comment: I have no idea gnasher729, I was not able to prove that this is a leibniz series if this is where you're going.

Comment: @TheCount 2n! not 2n.

Comment: @achillehui I have never seen this approximation before so I am not allowed to use it.

Comment: @gnasher729 the system is auto-clipping my link :(

Comment: @איתןלוי you are not allowed to use it in an assignment/exercise doesn't mean you cannot use it to figure out the right answer and stop wasting time on the wrong direction.

Comment: OP's responsiveness is quite admirable.

Comment: Hint: in the ratio test, it turns out $|a_{n+1} / a_n| > 1$ for all $n$.  Therefore, $|a_n|$ is strictly increasing so it can't converge to 0.

Comment: @DanielSchepler How did you reach this conclusion using the ratio test?

Comment: Calculated the terms the wrong way round in my head... Yes, if you expand (n!)^2 * 4^n, and (2n)!, then each term increases. If you take the different problem where numerator and denominator are swapped, that's more interesting because the terms shrink. You'd have to show they converge to 0. Then if you solve the problem without factor (-1)^n then you would have to prove it converges to 0 quickly enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&&4^n&=(1+1)^{2n}\\[4pt]
&&&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\\[4pt]
&&& > \binom{2n}{n}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence 
$$|a_n|=\frac{(n!)^2 4^n}{(2n)!}=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}} > 1$$
so the series diverges.

Comment: +1 clean and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Note $(n!)*2^n = (2n)!!$, so your sum is 
$$
\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^n * (n!)^2 * 4^n}{(2n)!} = \sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}
$$

Obviously 
$$
\left| \frac{(-1)^2(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!} \right| > 1
$$

So it does not converge

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$ a_n=\frac{4^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!} $$

it is a simple exercise to show that

$$ a_{n+1}>a_n $$

so

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n $$

fails to converge since $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^na_n\ne0$.